# How to write a locator and get both the text present in a single tag in HTML code for selenium automation

Tags: java, html, selenium

This is my html code

```
<h2>==$0
"How"
 "Are You"
</h2>
```

Writing locator like `//h2/text()[1]` for getting "How" text and writing `//h2/text()[2]` for getting "Are You" text doesn't works for me. Throws the below error

```
onException - WebDriver error:
<font color= 'red' size='3.5'>org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//h2/text()[2]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

Answer (score 1):

text() doesn't return webelement node but the text content

use instead

```
//*[text()[contains(.,"Are You")]]
```

now find the text as

```
elem.text()
```

you have to use string operator to extract the specific text you want